# Loading a hdf5 file and displaying the data with pyqtgraph

Tags: python, hdf5, pyqtgraph

I would like to show the data of a hdf5 file in the ImageView() class from pyqtgraph. The bare code of displaying the plot for ImageView() is:

```
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui
import pyqtgraph as pg

# Interpret image data as row-major instead of col-major
pg.setConfigOptions(leftButtonPan = False, imageAxisOrder='row-major')

app = QtGui.QApplication([])

## Create window with ImageView widget
win = QtGui.QMainWindow()
win.resize(800,800)
imv = pg.ImageView()
win.setCentralWidget(imv)
win.show()
win.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: ImageView')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

There is however also a hdf5 example in the pyqtgraph example set. I'm unfortunately not able to get it to work. I made some alterations to the example to make it work for my needs but I'm getting an error. Here is first the code:

```
import numpy as np
import h5py
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui

pg.mkQApp()

plt = pg.plot()
plt.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: HDF5 big data')
plt.enableAutoRange(False, False)
plt.setXRange(0, 500)


class HDF5Plot(pg.ImageItem):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        self.hdf5 = None
        self.limit = 10000  # maximum number of samples to be plotted
        pg.ImageItem.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)

    def setHDF5(self, data):
        self.hdf5 = data
        self.updateHDF5Plot()

    def viewRangeChanged(self):
        self.updateHDF5Plot()

    def updateHDF5Plot(self):
        if self.hdf5 is None:
            self.setData([])
            return

        vb = self.getViewBox()
        if vb is None:
            return  # no ViewBox yet

        # Determine what data range must be read from HDF5
        xrange = vb.viewRange()[0]
        start = max(0, int(xrange[0]) - 1)
        stop = min(len(self.hdf5), int(xrange[1] + 2))

        # Decide by how much we should downsample
        ds = int((stop - start) / self.limit) + 1

        if ds == 1:
            # Small enough to display with no intervention.
            visible = self.hdf5[start:stop]
            scale = 1
        else:
            # Here convert data into a down-sampled array suitable for visualizing.
            # Must do this piecewise to limit memory usage.
            samples = 1 + ((stop - start) // ds)
            visible = np.zeros(samples * 2, dtype=self.hdf5.dtype)
            sourcePtr = start
            targetPtr = 0

            # read data in chunks of ~1M samples
            chunkSize = (1000000 // ds) * ds
            while sourcePtr < stop - 1:
                chunk = self.hdf5[sourcePtr:min(stop, sourcePtr + chunkSize)]
                sourcePtr += len(chunk)

                # reshape chunk to be integral multiple of ds
                chunk = chunk[:(len(chunk) // ds) * ds].reshape(len(chunk) // ds, ds)

                # compute max and min
                chunkMax = chunk.max(axis=1)
                chunkMin = chunk.min(axis=1)

                # interleave min and max into plot data to preserve envelope shape
                visible[targetPtr:targetPtr + chunk.shape[0] * 2:2] = chunkMin
                visible[1 + targetPtr:1 + targetPtr + chunk.shape[0] * 2:2] = chunkMax
                targetPtr += chunk.shape[0] * 2

            visible = visible[:targetPtr]
            scale = ds * 0.5

        self.setData(visible)  # update the plot
        self.setPos(start, 0)  # shift to match starting index
        self.resetTransform()
        self.scale(scale, 1)  # scale to match downsampling


f = h5py.File('test.hdf5', 'r')
curve = HDF5Plot()
curve.setHDF5(f['data'])
plt.addItem(curve)

## Start Qt event loop unless running in interactive mode or using pyside.
if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys

    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

And here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyqtg.py", line 206, in <module>
    curve.setHDF5(f['data'])
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "/home/anaconda3/envs/img/lib/python3.8/site-packages/h5py-3.3.0-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg/h5py/_hl/group.py", line 305, in __getitem__
    oid = h5o.open(self.id, self._e(name), lapl=self._lapl)
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py/h5o.pyx", line 190, in h5py.h5o.open
KeyError: "Unable to open object (object 'data' doesn't exist)"
```

The problem is that I don't know what/how the hdf5 file looks so I am unsure how to replace 'data' with the correct term or if it is completely different in and of itself. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Edit 1:**
I got the examples from running `python -m pyqtgraph.examples`. Once the GUI pops up down the list you'll see "HDF5 Big Data". My code stems from that example. And from the examples the third one from the top, ImageView, is the code I would like to use to show the HDF5 file.

**Edit 2:**
Here is the result of running the second part of the code kcw78:
http://pastie.org/p/3scRyUm1ZFVJNMwTHQHCBv

**Edit 3:**
So I ran the code above but made a small change with the help from kcw78. I changed:

```
f = h5py.File('test.hdf5', 'r')
curve = HDF5Plot()
curve.setHDF5(f['data'])
plt.addItem(curve)
```

to:

```
with h5py.File('test.hdf5', 'r') as h5f:
    curve = HDF5Plot()
    curve.setHDF5(h5f['aggea'])
    plt.addItem(curve)
```

And got the errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anaconda3/envs/img/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyqtgraph/graphicsItems/GraphicsObject.py", line 23, in itemChange
    self.parentChanged()
  File "/home/anaconda3/envs/img/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyqtgraph/graphicsItems/GraphicsItem.py", line 458, in parentChanged
    self._updateView()
  File "/home/anaconda3/envs/img/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyqtgraph/graphicsItems/GraphicsItem.py", line 514, in _updateView
    self.viewRangeChanged()
  File "pyqtg.py", line 25, in viewRangeChanged
    self.updateHDF5Plot()
  File "pyqtg.py", line 77, in updateHDF5Plot
    self.setData(visible)  # update the plot
TypeError: setData(self, int, Any): argument 1 has unexpected type 'numpy.ndarray'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anaconda3/envs/img/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyqtgraph/graphicsItems/GraphicsObject.py", line 23, in itemChange
    self.parentChanged()
  File "/home/anaconda3/envs/img/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyqtgraph/graphicsItems/GraphicsItem.py", line 458, in parentChanged
    self._updateView()
  File "/home/anaconda3/envs/img/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyqtgraph/graphicsItems/GraphicsItem.py", line 514, in _updateView
    self.viewRangeChanged()
  File "pyqtg.py", line 25, in viewRangeChanged
    self.updateHDF5Plot()
  File "pyqtg.py", line 77, in updateHDF5Plot
    self.setData(visible)  # update the plot
TypeError: setData(self, int, Any): argument 1 has unexpected type 'numpy.ndarray'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyqtg.py", line 25, in viewRangeChanged
    self.updateHDF5Plot()
  File "pyqtg.py", line 77, in updateHDF5Plot
    self.setData(visible)  # update the plot
TypeError: setData(self, int, Any): argument 1 has unexpected type 'numpy.ndarray'
```

**Edit 4:**

Here is a photo of the results: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBXf9.jpg. I get the same empty results from both creating a 2d hdf5 file and using my 2d data file.

```
with h5py.File('mytest.hdf5', 'r') as h5fr, \
     h5py.File('test_1d.hdf5', 'w') as h5fw:
    arr = h5fr['aggea'][:].reshape(-1,)
    h5fw.create_dataset('data', data=arr)
    print(h5fw['data'].shape, h5fw['data'].dtype)
```

**Edit 5: The code that runs and plots**

```
import sys, os
import numpy as np
import h5py
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui

pg.mkQApp()

plt = pg.plot()
plt.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: HDF5 big data')
plt.enableAutoRange(False, False)
plt.setXRange(0, 500)

class HDF5Plot(pg.PlotCurveItem):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        self.hdf5 = None
        self.limit = 10000  # maximum number of samples to be plotted
        pg.PlotCurveItem.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)

    def setHDF5(self, data):
        self.hdf5 = data
        self.updateHDF5Plot()

    def viewRangeChanged(self):
        self.updateHDF5Plot()

    def updateHDF5Plot(self):
        if self.hdf5 is None:
            self.setData([])
            return

        vb = self.getViewBox()
        if vb is None:
            return  # no ViewBox yet

        # Determine what data range must be read from HDF5
        xrange = vb.viewRange()[0]
        start = max(0, int(xrange[0]) - 1)
        stop = min(len(self.hdf5), int(xrange[1] + 2))

        # Decide by how much we should downsample
        ds = int((stop - start) / self.limit) + 1

        if ds == 1:
            # Small enough to display with no intervention.
            visible = self.hdf5[start:stop]
            scale = 1
        else:
            # Here convert data into a down-sampled array suitable for visualizing.
            # Must do this piecewise to limit memory usage.
            samples = 1 + ((stop - start) // ds)
            visible = np.zeros(samples * 2, dtype=self.hdf5.dtype)
            sourcePtr = start
            targetPtr = 0

            # read data in chunks of ~1M samples
            chunkSize = (1000000 // ds) * ds
            while sourcePtr < stop - 1:
                chunk = self.hdf5[sourcePtr:min(stop, sourcePtr + chunkSize)]
                sourcePtr += len(chunk)

                # reshape chunk to be integral multiple of ds
                chunk = chunk[:(len(chunk) // ds) * ds].reshape(len(chunk) // ds, ds)

                # compute max and min
                chunkMax = chunk.max(axis=1)
                chunkMin = chunk.min(axis=1)

                # interleave min and max into plot data to preserve envelope shape
                visible[targetPtr:targetPtr + chunk.shape[0] * 2:2] = chunkMin
                visible[1 + targetPtr:1 + targetPtr + chunk.shape[0] * 2:2] = chunkMax
                targetPtr += chunk.shape[0] * 2

            visible = visible[:targetPtr]
            scale = ds * 0.5

        self.setData(visible)  # update the plot
        self.setPos(start, 0)  # shift to match starting index
        self.resetTransform()
        self.scale(scale, 1)  # scale to match downsampling


with h5py.File('mytest.hdf5', 'r') as h5fr, \
     h5py.File('test_1d.hdf5', 'w') as h5fw:
    arr = h5fr['aggea'][:].reshape(-1,)
    h5fw.create_dataset('data', data=arr)
    curve = HDF5Plot()
    curve.setHDF5(h5fw['data'])
    plt.addItem(curve)

## Start Qt event loop unless running in interactive mode or using pyside.
if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys

    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

**Edit 6:**
What worked in the end:

```
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import numpy as np
import h5py
import pyqtgraph as pg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

app = QtGui.QApplication([])

win = QtGui.QMainWindow()
win.resize(800,800)
imv = pg.ImageView()
win.setCentralWidget(imv)
win.show()
win.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: ImageView')

with h5py.File('test.hdf5', 'r') as h5fr:
    data = h5fr.get('aggea')[()] #this gets the values. You can also use hf.get('dataset_name').value as this gives insight what `[()]` is doing, though it's deprecated
    imv.setImage(data)

    # hf = h5py.File('test.hdf5', 'r')
    # n1 = np.array(hf['/pathtodata'][:])
    # print(n1.shape)
## Set a custom color map
colors = [
    (0, 0, 0),
    (45, 5, 61),
    (84, 42, 55),
    (150, 87, 60),
    (208, 171, 141),
    (255, 255, 255)
]
cmap = pg.ColorMap(pos=np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, 6), color=colors)
imv.setColorMap(cmap)

## Start Qt event loop unless running in interactive mode.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple example that shows how to extract data (as a 2d array) from a HDF5 file and plot with `pyqtgraph`. It also creates a plot from NumPy array (for comparison purposes -- the 2 methods are nearly identical).

- "Random" NumPy array data is generated for the `x=` and `y=` values in the first 2 plots.
- The `x=` and `y=` values are read from an HDF5 file for second pair of
  plots.

Only minor changes are required to work with your data. Changes required: 1) the HDF5 filename, and 2) the dataset names. You will have to figure out how to reshape your data from `shape=(1038,1388)` to appropriately shaped arrays for the X and Y data.

**Code below:**

```
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import numpy as np
import h5py
import pyqtgraph as pg

# create some HDF5 data in a 2-d array of X,Y pairs
with h5py.File('plot_2d_data.h5','w') as h5f:
    data = h5f.create_dataset('data',shape=(100,2))
    data[:,0] = np.arange(0.0,10.0,0.1) ## X data points
    data[:,1] = np.random.normal(size=100) ## Y data points

app = QtGui.QApplication([])

win = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget(show=True, title="2-D plot examples")
win.resize(1000,600)
win.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: 2D Plotting')

# Enable antialiasing for prettier plots
pg.setConfigOptions(antialias=True)

p1 = win.addPlot(title="Plot of NumPy data", 
                 x=np.arange(0.0,10.0,0.1), y=np.random.normal(size=100))

p2 = win.addPlot(title="NumPy data with Points", 
                 x=np.arange(0.0,10.0,0.1), y=np.random.normal(size=100),
                 pen=(255,0,0), symbolBrush=(255,0,0))

win.nextRow()

with h5py.File('plot_2d_data.h5','r') as h5f:
    
    p3 = win.addPlot(title="Plot of HDF5 data", 
                     x=h5f['data'][:,0], y=h5f['data'][:,1])

    p4 = win.addPlot(title="HDF5 data with Points", 
                     x=h5f['data'][:,0], y=h5f['data'][:,1],
                     pen=(0,0,255), symbolBrush=(0,0,255))

## Start Qt event loop unless running in interactive mode or using pyside.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

Comment: I'm marking this as the solution. I think I made it much harder to do as expected. I didn't need the big data example, just a simple hdf5 file opening like this one shows here. Thanks a lot for the help!!

Comment: Great! Glad that helped. I prefer simple when possible. Did you figure out how separate values in your large array into X and Y data?

Comment: Yea I added an edit to show what I used (edit 6). Essentially it doesn't matter if there is uneven amount of Xs and Ys in the data.

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that dataset `'data'` doesn't exist in your HDF5 file. So, we have to figure out why it's not there. :-) You didn't say where you found the example you are running. The one I found in the `pyqtgraph/examples` repository has code to create the file in function `def createFile(finalSize=2000000000):`.
I assume you ran this code to create `test.hdf5`?
If you didn't create the file with the example code, where did you get `test.hdf5`?
Either way, here is some code to interrogate your HDF5 file. It will give us dataset names and attributes (shape and dtype). With that info, we can determine the next steps.

```
import h5py
# define h5f as a h5py file object:
h5f = h5py.File('test.hdf5', 'r')
# print the dataset names and attributes
for ds in h5f.keys():
    if isinstance(h5f[ds], h5py.Group):
        print(f'{ds} is a Group')
    elif isinstance(h5f[ds], h5py.Dataset):
        print(f'{ds} is Dataset')   
        print(f'shape={h5f[ds].shape}, dtype={h5f[ds].dtype}')
    else:
        print(f'Object: {ds} is not a Group or a Dataset') 
h5f.close()
```

Expected output for test.hdf5 from the example:

```
# data is Dataset
# shape=(501000000,), dtype=float32
```

Below is a more general method using the `.visititems()` method to recursively check all objects in the hierarchy. I prefer/recommend when you have datasets organized under groups. Note: it uses Python's `with/as` context manager, which is preferred. Notice how `f.close()` is not required. It handles setup and tear down operations automatically, so doesn't leave a file open if your code exits unexpectedly.

```
import h5py
def visitor_func(name, node):
    if isinstance(node, h5py.Group):
        print(node.name, 'is a Group')
    elif isinstance(node, h5py.Dataset):
       if (node.dtype == 'object') :
            print (node.name, 'is an object Dataset')
       else:
            print(node.name, 'is a Dataset')   
    else:
        print(node.name, 'is an unknown type')    
     
#####  main  #####
with h5py.File('test.hdf5', 'r') as h5f:  
    h5f.visititems(visitor_func)
```

**Added 2021-08-20:**
We need to figure out why you get different behavior with your data compared to the example .hdf5 file. Run this little code segment with your file.

```
import h5py
h5f = h5py.File('test.hdf5', 'r')
ds = '/system.soft.avtcams.glasscellvert/absK40'
print(f'shape={h5f[ds].shape}, dtype={h5f[ds].dtype}')
print(f'type={type(h5f[ds])}')
h5f.close()
```

For reference, this is the output I get with the example test.hdf5 file:

```
# shape=(501000000,), dtype=float32 
# type=h5py._hl.dataset.Dataset
```

**Added 2021-08-21:**
Here is a test to see if you can use a NumPy array for the curve data. It reads the HDF5 dataset and reshapes from a 2-d dataset to a 1-d array. Hopefully this works. If not, I am out of ideas, and you will have to find someone with `pyqtgraph` expertise to diagnose the problem.

```
with h5py.File('test.hdf5', 'r') as h5f:
    curve = HDF5Plot()
    arr = h5f['/system.soft.avtcams.glasscellvert/absK40'][:].reshape(-1,)
    curve.setHDF5(arr)
    plt.addItem(curve)
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the comment. I updated my post to show where I got the example from. I tried your code and I got an error on the last print line: `'AttributeError: 'Group' object has no attribute 'shape'`

Comment: Yes that is the example I used but I have my own file that I called test.hdf5. I deleted the `def createfile()` part because I didn't need it since I have my own hdf5 file. Yes that is the example I used but I have my own file that I called test.hdf5

Comment: The code I posted was designed to work with the simple `test.hdf5` example file (which only has 1 dataset). Yours has at least 1 group, which makes it slightly more complicated. I will modify the code to account for groups. Also,  if you have a lot of groups, it is better to use `.visititems()` to recursively descend the file hierarchy.  I added a second bit of code to my answer to show how to do that.

Comment: Ok great thank you for that and apologies for the confusion. I updated my post with a link of the results.

Comment: No worries. I looked at your latest output. It's a LOT more complicated than the example - more groups and datasets, plus object references. (I'm curious; is this a Matlab file?) Now do you know which dataset has the values you want to plot?. **The HDF Group** has a utility called "HDFView" that is helpful when just getting started. It lets you view and explore the file's contents in a Java based GUI. You can download it here: [HDFView donwload](https://www.hdfgroup.org/downloads/hdfview/). Note: You need to create a free account, then login to download.

Comment: Thanks for the help! It was a struggle getting HDFView up and running as it doesn't work out of the box for Ubuntu 20.04. No it's not a Matlab file but I think it is from an inhouse package. I'll have a better answer for you I think with time as this is new for me. So I would like to plot for example absK40 in the `system.soft.avtcams.glasscellvert` folder. The data there is counts from a camera. Any idea how I can then get this to work with ImageView?

Comment: Once, you know the dataset name, accessing the data is easy. :-) Open the file object as `h5f`, and the dataset used by `curve.setHDF5(--)` is `h5f['/system.soft.avtcams.glasscellvert/absK40']`. This assumes that dataset is the correct shape for the method. You can check by printing the `.shape` attribute.

Comment: I made another edit with my attempt and am getting errors when I try to run the code. Any idea how I can fix it?

Comment: The traceback doesn't show which line of your code throws the error. :-( It's complaining about an `unexpected type 'numpy.ndarray'`. That is not what I would expect, b/c I the variable is a `h5py._hl.dataset.Dataset`. I added some code at the end of my previous answer to show how to compare the data in your test file to the example file.

Comment: I get the output: `shape=(1038, 1388), dtype=uint16
type=<class 'h5py._hl.dataset.Dataset'>`

Comment: I suspect the problem is the different shapes. The original is 1-d `(5000000,)` and yours is 2-d `(1038,1038)`. You could use `.reshape()` if pyqtgraph accepts a NumPy array (but I'm not sure about that). I don't know enough about pyqtgraph to diagnose beyond that.

Comment: How would I exactly use reshape? `curve` doesn't have a `.reshape`.

Comment: `.reshape()` is a NumPy method to modify the shape of an ndarray . It won't work with a HDF5 dataset. I looked at the `def updateHDF5Plot()` code. `self.hdf5` is the data passed for plotting. It uses `len()` to get the size before down-sampling, so I think it expects a 1-d object. However, I don't see why it can't use a NumPy array.  See code I added for a small modification that might work (however, it's an educated guess, so no guarantees).

Comment: It didn't work unfortunately. Comes up with the same error. Just want to mention one thing. The `HDF5Plot` was just created from pyqtgraph to show an example that pyqtgraph can work with hdf5 data. But maybe there is an issue within the class then? Maybe its not suitable for 2D data? Or what do you recommend I look into?

Comment: OK, I found the problem(s) and was able to plot data from a 2d dataset using the example code. (I have NOT tried to debug your code--taking it 1 step at at a time here.) The big problem was in the `class HDF5Plot()` declaration. The example has `pg.PlotCurveItem` and you changed to `pg.ImageItem`. The other change is the `.reshape()` method I added this morning. I put everything together in a NEW answer below.

Answer (score 1):

This is a new answer based the the Q&A in the comments above.

In addition to the coding errors described in my comments, there is a limitation in the example (`hdf5.py`). It is designed to show how to read 'big data" -- when the data doesn't fit in memory. It does this by reading the dataset in chunks and down sampling (as defined by `self.limit = 10000`). As a result, it ONLY reads data from 1d datasets. There is a workaround to use the code as-is with your data: create a little utility to extract the dataset of interest, reshape to a 1-d array and copy to a new hdf5 file. (This assumes the dataset of interest fits in memory. At some point, a longer discussion is required about HDF5 data vs NumPy arrays.)

To demonstrate this behavior, I created a new hdf5 file with a 2-d dataset that mimics the OP's data (`shape=(1038, 1388), dtype=uint16`). Here is the code to create the file (named `test_2d.hdf5`):

```
import h5py
import numpy as np    
chunk = np.random.random_integers(65535,size=(1038,1388)).astype(np.uint16)
# chunk = np.random.normal(size=1038*1388).astype(np.uint16).reshape(1038, 1388)    
with h5py.File('test_2d.hdf5', 'w') as h5f:
    h5f.create_dataset('data', data=chunk)
    print(h5f['data'].shape, h5f['data'].dtype)
```

After you create this file, use the code below to extract that data to a new file we will use to plot the data. (Assuming this works, this is "the solution". You can modify it to extract the data from your test file, then use that file to read and plot from the new file.)

```
import h5py
with h5py.File('test_2d.hdf5', 'r') as h5fr, \
     h5py.File('test_1d.hdf5', 'w') as h5fw:
    arr = h5fr['data'][:].reshape(-1,)    
    h5fw.create_dataset('data', data=arr)
    print(h5fw['data'].shape, h5fw['data'].dtype)
```

Finally, here is the slightly modified code from your original post. It is similar to yours, with the change  I described in the comments to the `class HDF5Plot()` declaration (use `pg.PlotCurveItem` instead of `pg.ImageItem`). That change is what triggered this error message: `TypeError: setData(self, int, Any): argument 1 has unexpected type 'numpy.ndarray'`

Code to plot:

```
import sys, os
import numpy as np
import h5py
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui

pg.mkQApp()

plt = pg.plot()
plt.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: HDF5 big data')
plt.enableAutoRange(False, False)
plt.setXRange(0, 500)

class HDF5Plot(pg.PlotCurveItem):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        self.hdf5 = None
        self.limit = 10000  # maximum number of samples to be plotted
        pg.PlotCurveItem.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)

    def setHDF5(self, data):
        self.hdf5 = data
        self.updateHDF5Plot()

    def viewRangeChanged(self):
        self.updateHDF5Plot()

    def updateHDF5Plot(self):
        if self.hdf5 is None:
            self.setData([])
            return

        vb = self.getViewBox()
        if vb is None:
            return  # no ViewBox yet

        # Determine what data range must be read from HDF5
        xrange = vb.viewRange()[0]
        start = max(0, int(xrange[0]) - 1)
        stop = min(len(self.hdf5), int(xrange[1] + 2))

        # Decide by how much we should downsample
        ds = int((stop - start) / self.limit) + 1

        if ds == 1:
            # Small enough to display with no intervention.
            visible = self.hdf5[start:stop]
            scale = 1
        else:
            # Here convert data into a down-sampled array suitable for visualizing.
            # Must do this piecewise to limit memory usage.
            samples = 1 + ((stop - start) // ds)
            visible = np.zeros(samples * 2, dtype=self.hdf5.dtype)
            sourcePtr = start
            targetPtr = 0

            # read data in chunks of ~1M samples
            chunkSize = (1000000 // ds) * ds
            while sourcePtr < stop - 1:
                chunk = self.hdf5[sourcePtr:min(stop, sourcePtr + chunkSize)]
                sourcePtr += len(chunk)

                # reshape chunk to be integral multiple of ds
                chunk = chunk[:(len(chunk) // ds) * ds].reshape(len(chunk) // ds, ds)

                # compute max and min
                chunkMax = chunk.max(axis=1)
                chunkMin = chunk.min(axis=1)

                # interleave min and max into plot data to preserve envelope shape
                visible[targetPtr:targetPtr + chunk.shape[0] * 2:2] = chunkMin
                visible[1 + targetPtr:1 + targetPtr + chunk.shape[0] * 2:2] = chunkMax
                targetPtr += chunk.shape[0] * 2

            visible = visible[:targetPtr]
            scale = ds * 0.5

        self.setData(visible)  # update the plot
        self.setPos(start, 0)  # shift to match starting index
        self.resetTransform()
        self.scale(scale, 1)  # scale to match downsampling

f = h5py.File('test_1d.hdf5', 'r')
curve = HDF5Plot()
curve.setHDF5(f['data'])
plt.addItem(curve)

## Start Qt event loop unless running in interactive mode or using pyside.
if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys

    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

**Plot created from my random data.**
[image: Plot created from my random data.]

Comment: Thanks for the write up! I first tested all of your code in your answer and there were no errors but the two plots are empty (no data) I looked at the `test_2d.hdf5` file and most values are 0 and some are 1 and 65535. I then tried it with my data i.e. instead of creating a 2D hdf5 file. The code I ran was is in edit 4 (I used your class in this answer). The code ran and the plots are still empty. The data in `test_1d.hdf5` is from my file (I can tell by the values) but still no data in the plots.

Comment: The plot is correct, but the psuedo-data is wonky because I used `np.random.normal()` to generate `np.uint16` values. I modified the code in my answer to use `np.random.random_integers()` and now you will get values between 1 and 65535.

Comment: A side note on your code in `def updateHDF5Plot)`: you changed variable `range_` to `xrange`. The author used `range_` because `range` is a Python function. `xrange` is a function in Python 2 ...so not exactly an error in Python 3, but better to not to use and avoid any confusion. Use `x_range` or similar.

Comment: Weird it's still not working for me. What do you mean the author used `range_`? The code from the example shows xrange. I didn't change any variable names. The only thing I changed was the `Imageitem``part but I changed that back. I am using your entire code now and it's not working for some reason. Are you using Python 3?

Comment: Ok just ran your code here again -- the one under the words "Code to plot" and that works i.e. I get values for the 1d plot. But if I then change the code to the other code starting with `with h5py.File('test_2d.hdf5', 'r') as h5fr, \ ` then it doesn't work.

Comment: Ok apologies for the spam but it finally works. I took some things from your other answers and added it to the code that was running form my previous comment. Edit 5 shows the complete code that runs. But the problem is that I would like a 2d graph and essentially this 1d graph is just all the values of the x and y plane in just one axis, right?

Comment: At this point your questions are about `pyqtgraph` functionality, not HDF5 data. Have you used `pyqtgraph` before? If not, you need to learn how to create a basic 2d plot. Start with the "Basic Plotting" example in the `pyqtgraph.examples`. I used it as a template along with some basic HDF5 tools to create a new answer (below) as starting point for your project. It is a lot simpler than the HDF5 example provided in their example.   As an aside, your data in an array of `shape=(1038,1388)`. How will you map it to X&Y data pairs?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236301/discussion-between-mikanim-and-kcw78).